# Detecting iphone version 4/4s and 5/5s/5c using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, iphone

I have accomplished detecting the version of iPhone like iphone 2,3,4,5 but what I am looking is to go for an extra mile, finding detailed versions like 4s/4 and 5/5s/5c but I have not found a solution yet.

I have used this script to check for iPhone 4 or 5:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
       var iHeight = window.screen.height;
       if(iHeight <= 480)
       {
          console.log('iPhone 2 or iPhone 3 or iPhone 3GS');
       }
       else if(iHeight > 480 && iHeight <=960)
       {
          console.log('iPhone 4');
       }
       else if(iHeight > 960)
       {
         console.log('iPhone 5');
       }
    });
```

I have also tried UserAgent but that string tells only iOS version not iPhone version.

Any help/clue would be appreciated! Thanks

Comment: I would also look at the phone orientation.